# I need to add code to tkinter exe program?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, tkinter, attachment

I want to be able to show the GUI user the code used to do background calculations. However copying and pasting and using "\n" in a text box takes forever. Now I know you can save the code as a pdf. Is there a simple way to attach the pdf to the program and the code still be readable even when it is moved to a different computer.

Main issues:
- How to import and attach a pdf to a button...
- How to include pdf into program so it is readable on any pc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which module are you using to create exe from python script?

Comment: pyinstaller.exe @Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Packaging:**

You can attach your code as pdf file with your program like this using pyinstaller

On Windows:

```
pyinstaller --add-data="relative/full_path_to_pdf;." my_script.py
```

On Linux:

```
pyinstaller --add-data="relative/full_path_to_pdf:." my_script.py
```

This will pack your pdf file and copy it to the same folder as the .exe package(in case of single file, it will extract it to the temp path along with main .exe which can be accessed with `sys._MEIPASS`) or You can change the extraction path instead of using '.' Read more [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search).

**In Code:**

You can add this type of button in your UI, to open the pdf file with the default viewer of Windows/Linux(same behavior as when you double click the file)

```
source_code_btn = Button(root, text="Source", command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('{} {}'.format(
                         "start" if os.name=="nt" else "xdg-open \"$@\" 2>/dev/null",
                          relative/full_path_to_pdf_file), shell=True))
```

Comment: How would I input my pdf file path? It says invalid syntax when doing relative/C:\Users\*****\*****\*****\****\*******\Code Pressure.pdf

Comment: There what I meant was either relative or full path to pdf file. So you can just use the full path directly.